# kusto KQL summarize argmax() returns modified column names

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, argmax

I have a quite big table as input where two fields (Id, StartTsUtc) form a unique key. the TimeStamp shows several updates for this unique key

[image: input data]

Wanting to keep only the latest update for each (Id,StartTsUtc), I'm applying the argmax function

```
| summarize argmax(TimeStamp, *) by Id, StartTsUtc
```

The result is correct, but the columns seem to have 'max_TimeStamp_' added in their column name

[image: result]

Why would that happen ? And how can this be avoided ?

Is there a way to easily remove 'max_TimeStamp_' from each columname ? The columns are dynamic, so it's not possible to use a project-rename using a fixed list

Answer (score 3):

You should use "arg_max()" instead of "argmax()". "argmax()" is the old version that had this undesirable behavior.

Comment: Indeed, that did the trick !! If all solutions would be that simple :) . Thanks for the fast response